# Solving the equation: $F''(r) + a(r)F'(r) + bF = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

How do I solve the following equation:

$$
F''(r) + \frac{1}{2}rF'(r) - \frac{1}{2}kF(r) = 0
$$

This equation is found when substituting the solution $u = t^{\frac{k}{2}}F(r)$ into the heat equation : $u_{xx} = u_t$.

The solution for $u$ is found by solving the characteristic equation:
$$
\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dt}{2t} = \frac{du}{ku}
$$
Where I get
$$
r = xt^{\frac{-1}{2}} \\
v = ut^{\frac{-1}{2}} \\
\text{where   } v = F(r) \\
u = t^{\frac{k}{2}}F(xt^{\frac{-1}{2}})
$$

The general solution given is:
$$
F(r) = c_1U(k+\frac{1}{2}, 2^{\frac{-1}{2}}r) + c_2V(k+\frac{1}{2}, 2^{\frac{-1}{2}}r)
$$

Where $U(p,z)$ and $V(p,z)$ are parabolic cylinder functions.

How do I arrive at the given solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is at least anoother solution for $$F''(r) + \frac{1}{2}rF'(r) - \frac{1}{2}kF(r) = 0$$ which looks very close to
[Hermite differential equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermiteDifferentialEquation.html).

Let $F(r)=e^{-\frac{r^2}{4}}G(r)$ to make
$$2 G''(r)-r G'(r)-(k+1) G(r)=0$$which does not look very different but easier to integrate making $r=2 x $.

So, using the solution given in the linked page, you should end with
$$G(r)=c_1 H_{-(k+1)}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)+c_2 \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{k+1}{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{r^2}{4}\right)$$ where appear Hermite polynomial and Kummer hypergeometric function.

Multiplied by $e^{-\frac{r^2}{4}}$, you arrive to the parabolic cylinder functions  (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function)).

Comment: I edited my question to add more information about how I arrived at $u, r, F(r)$